# Como selecionar um elemento tr no meio de "N tr's" no jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Possui uma tabela montada, que cada linha dela é adicionada dinamicamente. Assim sendo, dentro do `<tbody>` é adicionado as `<tr's>` (linhas).

Dentro das tr's, tem as `<td's>` e cada `<td>` possui um `input` dentro.

Imagine que eu posso adicionado 5 t's. Então se eu quero pegar um valor do primeiro `tr`, eu uso:

```
$('#d_sfiSRV003 #d_GRD_CENTROS_CUSTO tr:first-child').find('input#f_VLR_APROP_CCUST').val();

d_sfiSRV003 - id da pagina;
d_GRD_CENTROS_CUSTO - id da tabela
tr:first-child - seleciono o primeiro tr q tiver
input#f_VLR_APROP_CCUST - busco o input com a id referida e pego seu valor.
```

Mas se as tr's sao colocadas dinamicamente, como eu faço pra pegar por exemplo de 6 tr's colocadas, pegar o valor de `input#f_VLR_APROP_CCUST` do 4º tr ou de qualquer uma que eu escolher?

Comment: Todos os seus inputs terão o mesmo ID?

Comment: `first-child` não pega o primeiro, pega o primeiro filho.

Answer (score 1):

Não use `ids` para capturar elementos adicionados de forma dinâmica (nem para os que já existem). Um `id` deve ser único na página.

Altere a `id` `f_VLR_APROP_CCUST` para `class`: `class="f_VLR_APROP_CCUST"`.

Em seguida você irá conseguir pegar o valor do `input` com o seletor:

```
$('#d_sfiSRV003 #d_GRD_CENTROS_CUSTO tr:nth-child(numero_da_linha)')
.find('.f_VLR_APROP_CCUST').val()
```

Onde `numero_da_linha` é o número da linha que você quer achar o `input`.

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar o elementos sem saber seus ids você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

Pegar 3˚ tr:

```
$('tr:nth-child(3)')
```

Pegar tr com name:

```
$('tr[name="nome1"]'`)
```

Caso queria ainda pode saber quantos trs você tem deste modo:

```
var count = $('#id_objeto tr').length
```

Espero que isso te ajude!

Answer (score 0):

Com um loop simples, você pode trabalhar com todos os filhos de uma tag html de uma vez:

```
$("tr").each(function(){
    ... código ...
})
```

Entrado no loop você pode trabalhar com os objetos da forma como quiser

Pequise sobre a função each do jquery, ela é bem poderosa